# SelectionListener and SelectionAdapter

Tags: java, swt

I can't find this interface or other information about this:

```
    ok.addSelectionListener(new SelectionAdapter() {
      public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent e) {
      System.out.println("Your name is " + text.getText());
      shell.close();
      }
      });
```

- Does this interface named `SelectionListener`?((i.1)- why can't I find it on web? because it is not generic?)
- This selectionAapter is an**abstract class** which I implement with anonymous class?
- Why do I prefer this adapter over a handler external class?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Where have you found this code snippet?

Comment: In one of the tests that I'm taking for practice.

Comment: Yes, but these class names doesn't come out of the blue. You got them from somewhere, or you created them. That's why the question is strange... Given the accepted answer, you should at least have tagged the question SWT!

Comment: I don't get you. these are known class and interface. As part of my understanding the question I wondered how come i can't find them on the web and i couldn't recall whether they are interfaces/abstracts and so.. So I asked. What is the problem again? BTW- very very nice pictures!!

Comment: Thanks for the compliment. And, no, these are not so much widely known, and these are not part of the standard Java API, but part of some 3rd party library (here Eclipse/SWT), which I personally don't know (beside, the names are so generic, they can be part of lot of libraries). I mention this only to be educational about StackOverflow, and the general audience trying to help, not to put shame or anything. Tagging to provide context is important! :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[SelectionAdapter](http://help.eclipse.org/helios/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/swt/events/SelectionAdapter.html) is an abstract class that implements the [SelectionListener](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fswt%2Fevents%2FSelectionListener.html) interface.

It implements all the methods defined in that interface. You can use it if you only need specific code for some of them, otherwise implementing the interface directly is just as simple.

Comment: I have to stop using my local Google. Thanks a lot.